# Using defined constants to create objects

Tags: php

Arbitrary PHP question, more/less out of curiosity. I apologize if this is a silly question.

```
$class  = 'ClassName';
$object = new $class();
```

or

```
$object = $class::functionName();
```

This obviously works.

```
define(CLASS, 'ClassName');
$object = new CLASS();
```

or

```
$object = CLASS::functionName();
```

This does not work.

Just wondering if it is at all possible to use defined constants to create new objects. If not, I definitely understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do this:

```
define(MYCLASS, 'ClassName');
$class = MYCLASS;
$object = new $class();
```

...but as far as I know, you can't use the constant directly as in `new MYCLASS()`, because it will of course look for the class named `MYCLASS`.

Side note: You can't have constants with names that conflict with reserved words, like `class` or `function`, even if they are uppercased.

You could do something silly like this if for some reason you're doing this a lot:

```
function newClass($str, $args = NULL) {
    return new $str($args);
}
$class = newClass(MYCLASS);
```

...but I don't really recommend it. I'd also guess that you probably don't need so many constants, or there's a more elegant way to do what you're doing that doesn't involve constants at all.

Comment: Ya, that's exactly what I am doing currently in one of our older scripts. Just thought I'd ask. Thanks!